# UB-15MS10 Win 10 tablet Bios recovery

Tags: windows, windows-10, bios, tablet, recovery

Hi everyone I am struggling to recover Bios password , I cant login or , get into the bios or do a Boot from  USB , [Here is what I get when I turn it on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyBKH.jpg) Due Bios entry ,I ve tried three times and its locked , dont know what to do next , any suggestion is appreciated , thanks

Answer (score 1):

You cannot thwart or bypass the BIOS password request.  If you truly cannot remember or find the password, the tablet is just a brick now.

You will have to replace the tablet

Comment: Well to be honest before like 2 years Ago I took it to a technical service for installing a new windows to it ,  I message the guy who worked on it , I told him about the issue He doesnt  remember it  wtf I dont know what I am gonna do

Comment: Nothing you can do if you or the support person does not recall. You must replace the tablet

Comment: How about an easy and fast way For USB booting ?

Comment: Password locks in the last (roughly) five years have been made difficult / impossible to break.

Comment: As to starting in BIOS, look at your Tablet documentation. Often F1 will start in BIOS.

Comment: If you have proof of ownership you may try contacting the manufacturer's tech or customer support directly. Don't keep your hopes high though.

Comment: The manufacturer may require you to replace the Motherboard (including the BIOS chip).  That is is normally not economical.